# Backspace key not working in Vim/vi

Tags: vim

I just did some changes to the `.vimrc` file and `.bash_aliases` file and from that time I can't delete words with backspace key.

My `.vimrc` file has:

```
set nocompatible

set number
set incsearch
set autoindent
set ruler
set autowrite
set smarttab
set linebreak
set spell
set et
set title

set mouse=v
set history=50
set tabstop=4
set matchtime=2
set matchpairs+=<:>

syntax enable
filetype plugin indent on
filetype indent on
set sw=4

map <f2> :w\|!python %

hi SpellBad ctermfg=000 guifg=#000
```

And my `.bash_aliases` file has two line for Vim:

```
alias vim="vim -c 'startinsert' -u ~/.vim/.vimrc"
alias vi="vi -c 'startinsert' -u ~/.vim/.vimrc"
```

My `~/.vim` directory doesn't have a single plugin or script, so there's isn't any chance that plugin will cause this.

`~/.vim/.vimrc` is a symlink. The actual `.vimrc` file is in `~/vimrc/` directory which is a git repository.

Comment: This solved my issue: https://askubuntu.com/a/899059/525661

Comment: I was about to suggest stty erase ^H

Answer (score 266, accepted):

To allow backspacing over everything in insert mode (including automatically inserted indentation, line breaks and start of insert) you can set the [`backspace`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27backspace%27) option:

```
:set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

or

```
:set backspace=2  "compatible with version 5.4 and earlier
```

By default this option is empty, not allowing you to backspace over the above-mentioned things. This is the standard Vi behavior.

You can put this line to your `vimrc` file to have it set automatically when Vim starts:

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start  " more powerful backspacing
```

Also, starting from Vim 8.0 if no user vimrc file is found, Vim will set `backspace` to this value by loading the [`defaults.vim`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#defaults.vim) script.

Comment: it's still doesn't work for me =/ i've got 
`set backspace=2` 
`set backspace=indent,eol,start`
`fixdel`

Comment: @holms try `set backspace=2` alone

Comment: What the reason for such defaults where backspace is just moving caret to the left?

Comment: If you use vim80 above, see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52438373/vim81-configuration-wrong-after-i-added-vimrc

Answer (score 42):

Like a linux-newb, I was on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 install and my vim editor behaved differently than I was used to on the other machines I use (to include the backspace behavior you're describing). I didn't realize that I was actually using **vi** and not **vim** (both of which are executed with `vi`).

Installing **vim** and then editing a file brought back the behavior I was used to, including the backspacing working like I was expecting.

```
sudo apt install vim
```

Comment: Running this also color coded the text I was editing instead of it being completely gray (I was editing a BASH file) and it started telling me when I entered INSERT mode.

Comment: This fixed my problem (same as OP with the weird backspacing). Sometimes the simplest solution is the correct one. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

My `~/.vimrc` file had content `set nocompatible`. Added another line to the same file to make backspace work -

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

And just run

```
source ~/.vimrc
```

in the same terminal for change to take immediate effect in same shell. No need to open vi and run

```
:set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

Answer (score 13):

Nothing from above worked for me.
Tried `CTRL+backspace` it saved me

Answer (score 6):

I have compiled vim8.2 from source.Then I encouter this problem.
After insert `source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` in `.vimrc`. <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> works.

Answer (score 4):

For me，I had the setting below, however the backspace still doesn't work.

> `set backspace=indent,eol,start`

Finally, I found following line led to this problem.

> `inoremap <expr><C-h> neocomplete#smart_close_popup()`

When this setting is deleted, backspace key works well in insert mode.

`Reason`: That's because Vim sees CTRL-H as a backspace, and this line makes  remapped to neocomplete#smart_close_popup() in insert mode.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on a Debian 7.8 over SSH in urxvt + tmux.
I had vim and vim-tiny installed.

Removing vim-tiny fixed the problem.

Comment: This is kinda an old thread, but for me what's happening is that in vimtutor the backspace key is not working in insert mode, but in vim it does work in insert mode

Answer (score 1):

For me (Debian server, connected with "Konsole" from other linux), problems with backspace key and arrow keys were solved after uninstalling the vim-tiny package and installing the vim package.

Comment: Perhaps, these packages install different vimrc file(s).

Answer (score 1):

Many a times it is also a function of the getty type selected if one is using an SSH client like Putty or some such. Most preferable would be to use vt100+ as it is the most standard emulation.

I already had `:fixdel` which was not working. I had to remove it and replace it with the first suggestion to get it to work

Comment: I converts back space into delete