# vim81 configuration wrong after I added .vimrc

Tags: vim

I uninstalled vim74 and compiled vim81 and installed it. However I found it strange, comparing to vim74. When there's no .vimrc file under HOME dir, I open a c++ file and syntax highlight is working and I can use `Backspace` to delete letters. However when I add a .vimrc under HOME dir and just put `set number` into it, when the c++ source file is opened, no highlight, and `Backspace` not working. Why is that ? I used to add some configurations in .vimrc under vim74 before, and this situation never happens.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After complaints that Vim in its default configuration is hard to use (especially for beginners), it was decided to enable a default configuration if the user hasn't created his own `~/.vimrc` (yet). This was introduced with Vim 8.0, and explains what you're seeing (namely: syntax highlighting and sensible backspace behavior). Read more about the details at [`:help defaults.vim`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#defaults.vim).

The help also has instructions how to keep the defaults when adding your own `~/.vimrc` configuration:

> If you create your own .vimrc, it is recommended to add these lines somewhere
>   near the top:
>
> ```
> unlet! skip_defaults_vim
> source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
> ```
>
> Then Vim works like before you had a .vimrc.

Tip: Don't go all crazy with adding various snippets (especially not those you don't fully understand) and plugins to your `~/.vimrc`, even though the Internet is full of them. Rather, build it up gradually, depending on needs, and back up your understanding with careful studying of the excellent `:help`. Also, avoid pre-packaged *Vim distributions*; they're even worse.

Comment: Great ! Many Thanks !

Comment: Ah, glad I could help! Please accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark. This way, the question is marked as closed, and you increase your chances of getting answers to future questions, as this shows that you care about the answers.